# Loading selected properties from the Word JavaScript API context object

Tags: office-js

I'm developing a Word add-in using the Word JavaScript API and I need to load all the paragraphs in the document. The [ParagraphCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/javascript/api/word/word.paragraphcollection?view=word-js-preview) object is quite large and contains many properties I don't need.

In order to optimize the process, I'm trying to load only the [text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/javascript/api/word/word.paragraph?view=word-js-preview#text) property for each paragraph. However, no matter what I do, the Word add-in still loads filtered-out properties, just with an error message.

I have tried loading only the "text" field in the following ways:

```
context.document.body.paragraphs.load('text');
context.document.body.paragraphs.load(['text']);
context.document.body.paragraphs.load({ text: true });
```

However, in all three cases the `paragraphs.items` object contains all properties listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/javascript/api/word/word.paragraph?view=word-js-preview).

This is more or less what the output currently looks like:

```
{
  items: [
     {
       alignment: [Exception: RichApi.Error: The property 'alignment' is not available. Before reading the property's value, call the load method...],
       firstLineIndent: [Exception: RichApi.Error: The property 'firstLineIndent' is not available. Before reading the property's value, call the load method...],
       text: 'Some paragraph text',
       ...
     },
     ...
  ]
}
```

What I expect the output of ParagraphCollection to look like is the following:

```
{
  items: [
     {
       text: 'Some paragraph text'
       // No other properties should be loaded
     },
     {
       text: 'Some other paragraph text'
     }
  ]
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Morgan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the output that you desire, you can call `.toJSON()` on the object.  I.e.:

```
context.document.body.paragraphs.load('text');
await context.sync();
console.log(context.document.body.paragraphs.toJSON())
```

or if you want it in string form, you can substitute the following for the last line instead.  `JSON.stringify` automatically calls into `toJSON` underneath the covers:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(context.document.body.paragraphs, null, 4));
```

As for the reason:  the API objects that you are interacting with are *proxy objects*.  Thus, they have methods and placeholders for getters and setters even though the properties might not be loaded (and even though the objects themselves might not even exist within the document).  Whereas calling `toJSON()` will take all the loaded properties (if any) and give you a plain ol' JavaScript object corresponding to just the data.

Comment: Thanks, it works! I really appreciate the prompt response and the explanation. My only comment is that in your example it should be:
`context.document.paragraphs.toJson()` (i.e. you need to add "context").